# Differential algebra in Wikipedia and nlab

Tags: differential-algebra

The difference between the two definitions is clear in Wikipedia and nlab regarding the definition of a graduated algebra. 
*How to explain this nuance?*

***From Wikipedia:***

> A differential ring is a ring R equipped with one or more derivations, that are homomorphisms of additive groups
>   $\partial :R\to R\,$
>
> such that each derivation $\partial$  satisfies the Leibniz product rule
>   $$
> \boxed{ \partial (r_{1}r_{2})=(\partial r_{1})r_{2}+r_{1}(\partial r_{2}),}
> $$

for every $r_{1},r_{2}\in R$ .

***From nlab:***

> A differential algebra is an     associative algebra $A$ equipped with a derivation $d \colon A \to A$, typically required to satisfy
>    $$
> \boxed{d \circ d = 0}
> $$.

**Question** :Are these two definitions equivalent or is there some semblance of generalization?

Thanks in advance for your help and support.